# How to select the strings that only begin with specific prefixes

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to filter my query to only get the string that begin with these prefixes :

**AC / AY / AN / AZ / IR **

To do so i tried this SQL query :

```sql
select PN from MyTestTable where PN like 'AC%'  AND  PN like 'AY%' AND  PN like 'AN%' AND  PN like 'AZ%' AND  PN like 'IR %' ;
```

Is there a way to filter using a list or an other way ?

Comment: not the desired answer, but the `AND`s should be `OR`s

Comment: WHERE condition1 OR condition2 OR condition3 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the below query:

`SELECT PN FROM MyTestTable WHERE SUBSTR(PN,1,2) IN ('AC','AY','AN','AZ','IR')`

I hope this work for you .

Answer (score 0):

Create temp table and use join:

```
DECLARE @Pref TABLE (val nvarchar(20))
INSERT INTO @Pref
VALUES
('AC'),
('AY'),
('AN'),
('AZ'),
('IR')

SELECT t.PN 
FROM MyTestTable AS t
INNER JOIN @Pref p ON t.PN LIKE p.val+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` with a bunch of `or` conditions.  Or using [`regexp_like()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061494.html?pos=2):

```
select PN
from MyTestTable
where regexp_like(PN, '^(AC|AY|AN|AZ|IR )')
```

Note:  This includes the space after `'IR'` which appears to be part of the question.  If it is not needed, you could also use:

```
where left(PN, 2) in ('AC', 'AY', 'AN', 'AZ', 'IR')
```

Comment: Is regexp_like a valid regular expression in db2 ?  cause i'm getting an error using the query you provided  : [42601] [- 104] [SQL0104] Syntax element <END-INSTRUCTION> is not correct. Possible elements: <> = <> <=! <!>! => = ¬ <¬> ¬ = IN.

Comment: What's your db2 version and platform?